# Populating table with PHP keeps giving me common error

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to populate a table with data from the database. I have googled extensively but nothing seems to work

I always keep getting an empty table with following error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in

The thing is if I only give it 1 parameter then the page does gets stuck on the spinning loader.

Part of my html code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');   
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);  

session_start();
include 'config.php';

$query_string = "SELECT * FROM tbl_User";
                  
$query = mysqli_query($con, $query_string);


?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

....

</head>
<body>
   <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Profile Picture</th>
                  <th>Role</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <?php
                  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($con, $query)){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                  }    
                ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Code for config.php:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "chall") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
?>
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Don't pass connection into `mysqli_fetch_assoc($con, $query)){`

Comment: just as the error states; did you not read the manual(s)?

Comment: @Saty, yeah but if i leave it out. the page is stuck on my spinning loader ....

Comment: ok i will remove the loader and see if it works then

Comment: @GY22 *"the page is stuck on my spinning loader"* This tells us that you're using JS then; you should post that. Something may be failing you somewhere.

Comment: yeah the cause of my problem is the loader. so i removed it. strange ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Dont pass $con inside fetch_array/fetch_assoc